# The countdown timer is not reaching 0 Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

The countdown timer is not reaching 0 Android Firebase

Hello, the counter takes the Firebase realtime value. but does not reach zero it stops at number 1 and does not execute onFinish (). does anyone know what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

any help is welcome.

---

database structure

[image]

---

[image]

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userUid).child("cassino").child("cassinotime").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long v= Long.parseLong((String) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(v,1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        mQnATimer.setText("time : "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        final String userUid = user.getUid();
                        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                        ref.child("Users").child(userUid).child("money").setValue("250");

                    }
                }.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution
I'm create intent for a new activity

```
 @Override
                    public void onFinish()  {

                        Intent i=new Intent(Cassino.this,CassinoPayment.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
```

in CassinoPayment

```
@Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {





                        ref.child("Users").child(userUid).child("money").setValue("250");


                    }
                }
```

worked